# How to get all combinations of chars in string[] array items?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, combinations

Having a string array (for example): string[] arr = {"123","123","123"};
how to get all possible combinations of chars in array in items, like :111,121,131,112,113 and so on, taking just a single char from each item?

Comment: can you explain atleast what's the purpose of this?

Comment: You task description is utterly unclear. Please consider editing your question to make it more understandable. Best regards,

Comment: Are you thinking of [Permutations with Repetition?](http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html)

Comment: I have absolutely NO idea what you are asking for, if you have made any attempt at a solution, NOR what your actual issue is!

Comment: Your statement in regards to 'look elegant and beautiful' is confusing: are you asking us to write the code for you? Please show us your own code and clearly identify the problematic part.

Comment: Explain how do you get each combinations and what have you tried so far in programs...

Comment: OK, I have edited your question for better clarity. If this is OK, then the answer is rather straightforward: run nested loops (let's say with index i, j and k) and use String.Concat(arr[i], arr[j], arr[k]).

Comment: sounds like a high school comp sci test question.  Do your own homework :)

Comment: NO. have one way to achieve my needs.but it's Looks too ugly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
string _combinations = String.Empty;
for (int i=0; i<arr.Length;i++){
    for (int j=0; j<arr.Length;j++){
        for (int k=0; k<arr.Length;k++){
            combinations=String.Concat(combinations,arr[i], arr[j], arr[k], ",");
        }
    }
}
```

In case there are too many items in array, then make a recursive function call, adding chars from next array's item to each of previously calculated combinations in intermediary array returned by the function like the following one:

```
public string[] CalculateCombinationsArray( string[] array1, string NextItem)
{
    string _combinations = String.Empty;
    for (int i=0; i<array1.Length;i++){
        for (int j=0; j<NextItem.Length;j++){
            combinations=String.Concat(combinations,array1[i], NextItem.Substring(j,1), ",");
        }
    }
    return combinations.Split[","];
}
```

The rest you can do on your own.
Hope this will help.

Comment: if arr.length=100.Do you want to do 100 cycles?

Comment: if arr.length=100, it is the need to write 100 for?